# How to disable authentication requirement for apiDiscovery feature

Tags: swagger, websphere-liberty

Is there any way to disable the authentication requirement for accessing the API Documentation endpoints provided by the `apiDiscovery-1.0` feature?

I have the `apiDiscovery-1.0` feature enabled on Liberty 16.0.0.4.

I am able to see the swagger documents when I access `/ibm/api/explorer` as expected, but I am required to authenticate.

I am only able to authenticate by using credentials defined in a `basicRegistry` element within my `server.xml`. However, I want to eliminate this `basicRegistry` from my server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in the latest Beta (https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/)

With that driver, you only need apiDiscovery-1.0 (SSL is optional).

The default address for the public endpoint is http://host:port/api/explorer

You can change the "/api" portion by using the publicURL attribute in the apiDiscovery element in server.xml, for example:

```
<apiDiscovery publicURL="/myPublicAPI" />
```

This is targeted for Liberty's next release, 17.0.0.1.

Please note that in the public endpoint, internal endpoints (such as JMX, Batch, etc) are not displayed - only your deployed applications.

For the internal endpoints, you can use /ibm/api/explorer (which remains requiring SSL and authentication).

Comment: Thanks Arthur. I'll give the beta a shot, and look forward to moving up to 17.0.0.1 when it's released.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't remove the requirement for authentication for apiDiscovery for security reasons.
I doubt this helps but, you shouldn't "only be able to authenticate using credentials defined in a basicRegistry element within my server.xml" and instead any supported authentication mechanics should work like quickStartSecurity, LDAP, etc (and they can be set in any configuration file that is read by the server, not just server.xml).  For example, you should be able to use quickStartSecurity in wlp/usr/shared/config to apply an Admininistrator role for all servers under that /wlp/usr/servers/ directory.

Comment: You're right, that's not the _only_ way I am able to authenticate, but rather, I am only able to authenticate because I happen to have a basicRegistry entry in my server.xml.


Regarding security reasons, the app sits behind an external security framework, so I don't need to deal with authentication on the liberty container. It's disappointing that apiDiscovery needs authentication, as it'd be sitting behind the external security framework alongside my app.